# validate html5 two submit buttons .net

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a master page with a form field and a page with form fields in asp.net using html5 validation. Both sets of form fields have a submit button.  I am aware that they are on the same form once the page is compiled.

My problem is that all of the fields require validation.  I am using the required="required" attribute.  I prefer not to use the group validation from c#.

I need one field to be submitted if one button is selected and the other 3 fields to be submitted if the other button is selected.  As of right now, if either button is submitted, ALL form fields must be filled out.  One of the form fields and button is in the master page for a newsletter subscription and the other fields and button are on a page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Justice

Page Code:

```
              <div class="form-group">
                <input runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="register_email" id="register_email" class="form-control" required="required" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone" name="register_phone" id="register_phone" class="form-control" required="required" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group text-center">                      
                <button runat="server" data-loading-text="Please wait..." class="btn btn-dark btn-theme-colored btn-sm btn-block mt-20 pt-10 pb-10" id="submit2" name="submit2" onServerClick="Submit_Click2">Send Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Mater Page Code:

```
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input runat= "server" name="emailOut" id="emailOut" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control input-lg font-16" data-height="45px"  />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button runat="server" data-height="45px" class="btn btn-colored btn-theme-colored btn-xs m-0 font-14" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onServerClick="Submit_Click" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" >Get Started</button>
                        </span>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Use the aspnet Validation Controls with a ValidationGroup.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I prefer not to use the Validation Controls with .net.  The inline formatting doesn't flow with my pages.